# How can I prove a contradiction follows from P <-> Q and P -> ~Q?

Tags: logic, fitch

I am so close to solving this problem: (Language Logic and Proof 8.36).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zMnZ.jpg

All I need to do to complete the proof is show that P <-> Q and P -> ~Q is a contradiction (the problem has a similar form to this)

How can I do this? Intuitively, P <-> Q is (P -> Q) ^ (Q -> P) which can be translated to

(~P V Q) ^ (~Q V P) and that

P->~Q has this form (~P V ~Q) which is not equivalent to either of the above expressions (let alone both of them!).

Am I missing something really obvious? Is there another way to complete this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We cannot derive a contradiction from **P ↔ Q** and **P → ¬Q**, because the the two formuale are simultaneously *satisfiable*.

It is enough to consider a *truth assignment* **v** such that:

> **v(P)=v(Q)=false**.

Comment: Gotcha! That's where the intuition (when I tried the neg. intro) was pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

We have `P <-> Q` and `P -> ~Q`, and we want to derive a contradiction.

Maybe you could try to show `~(P <-> Q)`?

One suggestion here might be to try supposing `P`.

Then we have `~Q` by detachment, implying `~(P -> Q)` -- which looks like possibly a counterexample to `P <-> Q`, maybe helping to get you to `~(P <-> Q)`?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

```
P -> Q ≡ ~Q -> ~P
```

Thus

If P -> ~Q, then by Syllogism we have:

```
(P-> ~Q) ^ (~Q -> ~P)  ⇒ P -> ~P
```

Comment: True but P -> ~P is not a contradiction. It is satisfiably true when P is false. P ^ (P -> ~P) would be a contradiction.

Comment: @virmaior - Good point. Strictly speaking, ~P^P is called a contradiction, and yes it is not the same as P -> ~P.

Comment: P -> ~P is simply a proof of not ~P. There's no contradiction involved.

Comment: @virmaior - ~P v ~P. Excellent point.